# how to update table1 from the data of table2

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

1. agentmast [ AGNT_CODE,AGNT_NAME,etc]  It is a master table contain 4000+ records
2. emi [AGNT_CODE,FULLNAME, etc] It is a transaction table contain 30 - 40 records

I want to replace all FULLNAME in emi with values from agentmast.AGNT_NAME if AGNT_CODE exists in both the tables.

Please help

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
UPDATE EMI e 
JOIN agentmast a ON e.AGNT_CODE = a.AGNT_CODE 
SET e.FULLNAME = a.AGNT_NAME
```

Search on here for 'update with join mysql' for more potential examples'

Comment: `SET e.FULLNAME = a.AGNT_NAME`